# String.StartsWith does not work as I expect

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string word1 = ""; //see example   
string word2 = "";    
bool b1 = word1.StartsWith(word2);
bool b2 = word1.Substring(0, word2.Length) == word2;
```

for some Arabic strings b1 does not equal b2?
Could you explain this behavior?

Example:

```
word1 = ((char)0x0650).ToString()+ ((char)0x0652).ToString()+ ((char)0x064e).ToString();
word2 = ((char)0x0650).ToString()+ ((char)0x0652).ToString();
```

Comment: Could you please give some examples?

Comment: @Ahmed They both evaluate to `true` as expected.

Comment: I have arabic string break this case!

Comment: @Ahmed If you have a case that breaks it, then please supply that case. That would be more "useful".

Comment: You are returning a bool value, true or false, b1 can't equal b2 unless they are the same boolean value

Comment: I added an example, I could not put the actual string, as it displayed as rubbish, I putted the actual hexa codes instead, these character sequence is the vowel letters in Arabic

Comment: Make sure that your string doesnt start with the BOM mark is your're using UNICODE

Comment: @DanielPeñalba, Sure, the example itself does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference: [.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) performs a culture sensitive comparison, while [.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) (what you use with ==) doesn't.

So if you have two strings, that are different when you compare them character-by-character (== returns false), but are considered equal by your culture (startswith returns true), you could get this result.

**EDIT** 
If I try your example values with this:

```
bool b1 = word1.StartsWith(word2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
bool b2 = word1.Substring(0, word2.Length).Equals(word2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

both return "True".

Comment: I used all the StringComparison values, but it is the same output

Comment: But I'm using the Arabic Culture, in this case it should give the same result, also in case of InvariantCulture it does not

Comment: @Ahmed [Performing Culture-Insensitive String Comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/885e1sy1.aspx)